# PHPMailer and no attachment selected - cannot send email - form disappeared

Tags: php, email, webforms, phpmailer

I'm not a PHP programmer so I'm asking for any help.
I try to send multiple attachments using PHPMailer function from a web form

When I select file or files and click on Send button I can receive email succesfully.

The problem is when I DO NOT SELECT any attachment. When I click on Send button and I do not add any attachment to my form I just get a blank web page - all my web form is not visible.

Can anybody help me and give any solution to my issue? Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ownerName']) && (!empty($_REQUEST['ownerName']))){
           
           $mail = new PHPMailer;

           $mail->setFrom($ownerEmail);
           $mail->addAddress($ownerEmail);
           $mail->AddReplyTo($ownerEmail);
           $mail->Subject = 'Ubezpieczenia podróży - zapytanie o oferte';
           $mail->msgHTML("
           <html><body>
           <h2>DANE KLIENTA / DANE KONTAKTOWE:</h2>
           <table style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Imie</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>Nazwisko</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>PESEL</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>Telefon</th ><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Email</th>
           </tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$ownerName</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>$ownerSurname</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$ownerPESEL</th><th style='border: 1px 
solid black;'>$ownerPhoneNumber</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$ownerEmail</th>
           </tr>
           </table>
           <h2>DANE PODRÓŻY:</h2> 
           <table style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Strefa wyjazdu</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>Liczba osób poniżej 26 lat</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Liczba osób pomiędzy 26 a 
65 lat</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Liczba osób powyżej 65 lat</th><th style='border: 1px 
solid black;'>Początek okresu ubezpieczenia</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>Koniec okresu 
ubezpieczenia</th>
           </tr>
           <tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
           <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$TripDirection</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>$amountOfLess26</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$amoountOfBetween26and65</th><th 
style='border: 1px solid black;'>$amountOfMoreThan65</th><th style='border: 1px solid 
black;'>$insuranceStartDate</th><th style='border: 1px solid black;'>$insuranceEndDate</th>
           </tr>
           <table>
           </body></html>
           ");

           foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
              $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
           }
          
           $mail->IsHTML(true);
           $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
  

           if(!$mail->send()){
              echo "Błąd w trakcie wysyłania wiadomości: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           }else{
              echo "Dziękujęmy za wysłanie wiadomości!";
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

after few hours I found solution.
I needed to add

```
require_once("src/Exception.php");
```

And all email works good with and without attachments